# Getting Revisions from CVS repository

Tags: repository, cvs

I am trying to get somehow all the revision log that were made to a particular file,
but I seem to stupid to do that :(

To checkout a module I do the following

```
CVSROOT="/home/projects/stuff/" cvs co myworkingdir
```

within myworkingdir I have a testfile called paper.tex and from this I wanna try
to get the revisions but I tried the following but nothing works ...

```
CVSROOT="/home/projects/stuff/" cvs log paper.tex
cvs log: cannot open CVS/Entries for reading: No such file or directory
cvs log: nothing known about paper.tex

-bash-3.2$ CVSROOT="/home/projects/stuff/" cvs log myworkingdir/paper.tex
cvs [log aborted]: no such directory `myworkingdir'
```

Anyone an idea how I could get the log of the revisions of the paper.tex file
in the myworkingdir module?

Many thanks for your help!
Claus

Comment: It sounds like something went wrong with the checkout and the CVS files aren't actually there. Can you check if the other CVS operations work (like commit, update, etc)?

Comment: yeah, it looks as if they work. so it should work the way I have done it? thanks

Comment: I don't believe there is anything wrong with your commands, although I'm not 100% sure. Is the myworkingdir/paper.tex file actually there? is the hidden CVS directory in myworkingdir/ there?

Comment: The error "Cannot open CVS/Entries for reading" usually means that you are not inside a sandbox (i.e. a folder checked out from CVS) while running the command. From where are you running this?

Answer (score 0):

The error "Cannot open CVS/Entries for reading" usually means that you are not inside a sandbox (i.e. a folder checked out from CVS) while running the command.
Please also note that `cvs log` will never use the CVSROOT environment variable. Instead, it reads the connection string from the current directory's sandbox meta data, i.e. the ./CVS/Root file. This is also why you need to be located inside a valid sandbox when running `cvs log`.

If you want to log a file without checking it out first, you can do the following:

```
cvs -d/home/projects/stuff rlog myworkingdir/paper.tex
```

---

However, is /home/projects/stuff really the location of your repository? Or is it maybe rather the location of your working copy? If it is the location of your repository then there should be a folder /home/projects/stuff/CVSROOT containing all kinds of administrative files (e.g. modules, loginfo, commitinfo, cvswrappers, etc.).

In any case, make sure your working copy is located somewhere else entirely (i.e. not anywhere under /home/projects/stuff).